# No me carga los estilos cuando uso ngFor

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una consulta a un servicio en nodeJs, cuando obtengo los datos en angular y quiero mostrarlos en un slider, no carga el css y los divs se constriyen uno debajo de otro sin mostrar la animación del slider.

Les coloco el codigo html donde realizo el ngfor

```
<section class="testimonial section" id="testimonial">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- testimonial wrapper -->
            <div class="testimonial-slider">
                <!-- testimonial single -->
                <div class="item text-center" *ngFor="let cliente of GetClientes">
                    <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                    <!-- client info -->
                    <div class="client-details">
                        <p>{{cliente.comentario}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /client info -->
                    <!-- client photo -->
                    <div class="client-thumb">
                        <img src="../../../assets/images/client-logo/clients-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="client-meta">
                        <h3>{{cliente.nombre}}</h3>
                        <span>{{cliente.descripcion}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /client photo -->
                </div>
                <!-- /testimonial single -->


            </div>
        </div> <!-- end col lg 12 -->
    </div> <!-- End row -->
</div> <!-- End container -->
```

Me carga todo la información del servicio node pero no toma los estilos.
Les coloco una imagen de cómo se carga el slider.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si lo coloco sin el ngFor si me toma los estilos correctamente como en el siguiente codigo:

```
<section class="testimonial section" id="testimonial">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- testimonial wrapper -->
            <div class="testimonial-slider">
                <!-- testimonial single -->
                <div class="item text-center">
                    <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                    <!-- client info -->
                    <div class="client-details">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos
                            earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates
                            alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia.
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /client info -->
                    <!-- client photo -->
                    <div class="client-thumb">
                        <img src="../../../assets/images/client-logo/clients-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="client-meta">
                        <h3>William Martin</h3>
                        <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /client photo -->
                </div>
                <!-- /testimonial single -->

                <!-- testimonial single -->
                <div class="item text-center">
                    <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                    <div class="client-details">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos
                            earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates
                            alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia.
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="client-thumb">
                        <img src="../../../assets/images/client-logo/clients-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="client-meta">
                        <h3>Emma Harrison</h3>
                        <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /testimonial single -->


            </div>
        </div> <!-- end col lg 12 -->
    </div> <!-- End row -->
</div> <!-- End container -->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin el ngFor carga la animación y el slider va corriendo.

Como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Podrias colocar tu css para poder conocer como esta construido, gracias

Comment: Agrega como se esta renderizando en __*ngFor__ en el inspector de elementos en el navegador.